# How to dowload safari certificate for windows?

Tags: watir

I am trying to automate a Safari browser using Watir. I have created an apple account and have validated my account. I am following instructions on this link: http://watirwebdriver.com/safari/

But I was not able to create a safari extension. Kindly help me. I am able to log into Developer Certificate Utility page but not beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a bit more information, please.  I just went to the URL you gave and was able to get Safari working with Watir-WebDriver.  I did have to do the following, but not sure what step actually got it to work properly.

1. Shut down Safari.
2. Reloaded Safari and re-downloaded my certificate.
3. Shut down Safari.
4. Reloaded Safari and attempted to re-add the extension.
5. Extension was already pre-loaded and had the proper certificate.

Comment: there is nothing to download for me, its blank

Comment: Did you go to http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver ?  There's nothing on the Watir webdriver site to download.